# Failed to build Go application: ... : can't find import: "code.google.com/p/go.net/html

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go, package, importerror

I have just attempted to launch an application (https://github.com/mjibson/goread) on google app engine.

I have followed all the steps but when I get to the point where I should launch it with `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` I am getting the following error :

```
$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml                                                                                                   
INFO     2013-11-27 17:14:13,250 sdk_update_checker.py:245] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-11-27 17:14:13,446 sdk_update_checker.py:273] The SDK is up to date.
WARNING  2013-11-27 17:14:13,455 api_server.py:331] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-11-27 17:14:13,460 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:42131
INFO     2013-11-27 17:14:13,532 dispatcher.py:171] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-11-27 17:14:13,535 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2013-11-27 17:14:16,293 go_runtime.py:166] Failed to build Go application: 
2013/11/27 17:14:16 go-app-builder: build timing: 10×6g (2.35416362s total), 18×gopack (104.629743ms total), 0×6l (0 total)
2013/11/27 17:14:16 go-app-builder: failed running 6g: signal: killed


(Executed command: /home/ubuntu/bin/go_appengine/goroot/bin/go-app-builder -app_base /home/ubuntu/mygo/src/github.com/mjibson/goread -arch 6 -binary_name _go_app -dynamic -extra_import$
 appengine_internal/init -goroot /home/ubuntu/bin/go_appengine/goroot -nobuild_files ^^$ -unsafe -work_dir /tmp/tmpJex0GQappengine-go-bin -gcflags -I,/home/ubuntu/bin/go_appengine/goroo
t/pkg/linux_amd64_appengine -ldflags -L,/home/ubuntu/bin/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/linux_amd64_appengine -gopath /home/ubuntu/mygo sanitizer/sanitize.go rdf/rdf.go rss/rss.go types.go fun
cs.go utils.go settings.go atom/atom.go sanitizer/strip.go main.go admin.go charge.go user.go autodiscover.go sanitizer/snip.go tasks.go)
^CINFO     2013-11-27 17:14:18,348 shutdown.py:44] Shutting down.
INFO     2013-11-27 17:14:18,375 api_server.py:524] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2013-11-27 17:14:18,375 api_server.py:527] Saving search indexes
```

With sudo only the error part change :

> ERROR    2013-11-27 15:04:50,576 go_runtime.py:166] Failed to build Go
>   application:
>   /home/ubuntu/mygo/src/github.com/mjibson/goread/sanitizer/sanitize.go:21:
>   can't find import: "code.google.com/p/go.net/html"

The lines causing problems :

package sanitizer

```
 17 package sanitizer
 18 
 19 import (
 20         "bytes"
 21         "code.google.com/p/go.net/html"
 22         "io"
 23         "net/url"
 24         "strings"
 25 )
```

This is my go environment :

```
$ goapp env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/ubuntu/mygo"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/ubuntu/bin/go_appengine/goroot"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/ubuntu/bin/go_appengine/goroot/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CGO_ENABLED="1"

$ ll ~/bin/
Nov 27 14:34 appcfg.py -> go_appengine/appcfg.py*
Nov 27 14:34 dev_appserver.py -> go_appengine/dev_appserver.py*
Nov 18 01:36 go_appengine/
Nov 27 14:35 goapp -> go_appengine/goapp*

/home/ubuntu/mygo/pkg/
└── linux_amd64_appengine
    └── code.google.com
        └── p
            └── go.net
                ├── html
                │   └── atom.a
                └── html.a
/home/ubuntu/mygo/src/
├── code.google.com
│   └── p
│       ├── go-charset
│       │   ├── charset
│       │   ├── cmd
│       │   ├── data
│       │   ├── datafiles
│       │   └── lib
│       └── go.net
│           ├── dict
│           ├── html
│           ├── idna
│           ├── ipv4
│           ├── ipv6
│           ├── netutil
│           ├── proxy
│           ├── publicsuffix
│           ├── spdy
│           └── websocket
└── github.com
    ├── gorilla
    │   ├── context
    │   └── mux
    ├── MiniProfiler
    │   └── go
    │       ├── example
    │       ├── miniprofiler
    │       ├── miniprofiler_gae
    │       ├── miniprofiler_revel
    │       ├── redis
    │       ├── sql
    │       └── ui
    └── mjibson
        ├── appstats
        │   └── static
        ├── goon
        └── goread
            ├── atom
            ├── rdf
            ├── rss
            ├── sanitizer
            ├── static
            └── templates
```

App engine version : `linux_amd64-1.8.8`

**EDIT**

```
Now I am getting 
ERROR    2013-11-28 02:11:38,201 go_runtime.py:166] Failed to build Go application: /home/ubuntu/mygo/src/github.com/MiniProfiler/go/miniprofiler/static.go:19263: out of memory
```

ALthough I have like 480M of free RAM on my machine while running this command.

**EDIT**

I have tested and seems that there is not enough RAM on the machine that I wanted to run it on (free tier amazon instance) because it runs smoothly on my local machine with the following `htop` summary

```
 VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
1492M 88588  5804 S  0.0  1.5  0:14.72 python /home/XXXX/bin/dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

Comment: So did you get the package from github or code.google.com? because if you're using that package in your imports you should have those files in the exact structure in the "pkg/src" folders.  I would say do a new "go get" from github and try compiling that again, but before that delete the current imported package you have in your gopath

Comment: @YasirG. I am getting it from github (I think the project needs some dependencies from `code.google.com`). Still I do not use `go get` but `goapp get -d github.com/mjibson/goread`.

Comment: I see, I guess you need to fetch that package as well, it must be one of those packages that were in the framework but got moved to separate repositories like bcrypt and other packages. Since you're using a specific tool that works like "go get" try fetching that package in the following way: goapp get code.google.com/p/go.net/html. Let me know what happens.

Comment: @YasirG. I can fetch them but still I already have them as pointed out in the last command `ls /home/ubuntu/mygo/src/code.google.com/p/go.net/html/`

Comment: Normally if gopath contains the required packages things would compile without any issues.  Right now my only guess is that it's looking in some other path for this package. Can you check if there are any config files with that tool that are pointing to other paths or other directory structure?

Comment: Is there any more output from `dev_appserver.py` besides what you copied? What version of the SDK are you running?

Comment: @Dave I have updated my answer with the whole error message. The appengine version is `linux_amd64-1.8.8`

Comment: Miniprofiler and appstats use lots of memory during compilation since they include huge byte arrays of static content - this is probably causing the OOM errors. Do you have any errors now besides that? I don't think there's a real problem here.

Comment: @mjibson Hi, there. Well I have tried to run it locally on my machine and it works ok. I have tried copying the `pkg` folder to the other machine but it didn't work (the same output) even on explicit `goapp build`

Comment: I think the not finding the package when you run as `sudo` is expected: it's likely that your gopath is not readable to the superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  have tested and seems that there is not enough RAM on the machine that I wanted to run it on (free tier amazon instance) because it runs smoothly on my local machine with 6 GB of RAM.